# Can a pointed lightning rod prevent a lightning strike?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, lightning

Will a pointed lightning rod disperse the ground charge into the air sufficient enough to prevent the ground charge from building and attracting a lightning bolt?

Answer (score 0):

A lightning rod makes sure that the charge from lightning(negative in this case) passes through it , as it produces a low resistance path to the negative charge to flow towards the ground when compared with other stuff's resistance like buildings trees etc. This is because lightning rods are good conductors of electricity . So while they do not "Prevent"  the ground charge to stop attracting the electric charge in lightning , they tend to attract them and provide a safe pathway so that buildings and other materials remain safe.